# Cannot send session cache limiter?

Tags: php, html, dom

I have develop my site that required login. If user not yet login it will redirected to login page. But i have problem after i click login, here is problem:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at ......../corporateuser/request.php:1) in ........../corporateuser/request.php on line 2

Here is the code:

```
1. <?php
2. session_start();
3. if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
4.  header("Location:login.php");
5.  exit();
6. }
7. include_once("action.php");
8. ?>
```

What is the problem with that warning, line 1 and 2?

Comment: Check there is no white space above `session_start();`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: @Rikesh, there is no whitespace.

Comment: Still try pressing delete & take session_start() at very first line & check.

Comment: @Rikesh, I have tried, but it still not work :( anymore solution?

Comment: i have already used, it not work

Answer (score 0):

You have to put session_start(); on the top of your php page. is this the top?

for example:

```
<html>
<head>
//stuff
</head>
<body>
//beginning of page:
<?php session_start();
//rest of code.
?>
</body>
</html>
```

otherwise:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
session_start();
header("Location:login.php");
exit();
}
include_once("action.php");
?>
```

**NOTE: this probably fixes your first error. (Line 1)**

Comment: that session_start() is on the top